# C# OWIN Security - set expiration token - always have default value

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, asp.net-identity, owin

hello everyone I currently have a project where I use owin security

when I try to make the request to / token I get this

[image]

there specifies that the expiration token is at 7199 seconds (2 hours)

I was looking for this endpoint (route) but I did **not fond** **/token** it or find the place where they set this value to 2 hours **(look in the whole solution)**

The only thing I found was this class that corresponds to the refresh token **(but no expiration token)** but this token is set to 14400 and yet when I make the request again the token always remains at that value

```
namespace Conarch.Providers
{
    public class SimpleRefreshTokenProvider : IAuthenticationTokenProvider
    {

        public async Task CreateAsync(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
        {
            var clientid = context.Ticket.Properties.Dictionary["as:client_id"];

            context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(12000));

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientid))
            {
                return;
            }

            var refreshTokenId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n");

            using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())
            {
                var refreshTokenLifeTime = context.OwinContext.Get<string>("as:clientRefreshTokenLifeTime"); 

                var token = new RefreshToken() 
                { 
                    Id = Helper.GetHash(refreshTokenId),
                    ClientId = clientid, 
                    Subject = context.Ticket.Identity.Name,
                    IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(refreshTokenLifeTime)) 
                };

                context.Ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = token.IssuedUtc;
                context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = token.ExpiresUtc;

                token.ProtectedTicket = context.SerializeTicket();

                var result = await _repo.AddRefreshToken(token);

                if (result)
                {
                    context.SetToken(refreshTokenId);
                }

            }
        }

        public async Task ReceiveAsync(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
        {

            var allowedOrigin = context.OwinContext.Get<string>("as:clientAllowedOrigin");
            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { allowedOrigin });

            string hashedTokenId = Helper.GetHash(context.Token);

            using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())
            {
                var refreshToken = await _repo.FindRefreshToken(hashedTokenId);

                if (refreshToken != null )
                {
                    //Get protectedTicket from refreshToken class
                    context.DeserializeTicket(refreshToken.ProtectedTicket);
                    var result = await _repo.RemoveRefreshToken(hashedTokenId);
                }
            }
        }

        public void Create(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Receive(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

**My question is**: in what place do you set this value and how could the time increase?

thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set the expiration time during your web application configuration
Use this:

```
OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()  
{  

    AllowInsecureHttp = true,  
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),  
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),  
    Provider = new AuthorizationServerProvider(),  
    RefreshTokenProvider = new RefreshTokenProvider()  
};
```

You may find the full article [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/angularjs-enable-owin-refresh-tokens-using-asp-net-web-api/)

Comment: I fixed the link

Comment: I have this exact setup but my token always comes out with 1 hour expiration.  Regard of my setting here or in my provider overrides.